# ruby on rails validation does not show the error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my validation does not show the error messages.
Instead of showing error messages, incorrect save data displays the error like this,

```
 Missing template employees/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

My model is,

```
  validates :emp_firstname, :presence=> {:message=>" cannot be blank"},
             :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z@\.\s]*\z/, :message => "only alphabets."}
validates :emp_lastname, :presence=> {:message=>" cannot be blank"},
             :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z@\.\s]*\z/, :message => "only alphabets."}
validates :address
validates :email_id, :presence=> {:message => "cannot be blank."},
             :format => { :with =>  /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :message => "Give Correct format"}
```

My view page is,

```
    <% if @employee.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@employee.errors.count, "error") %> Errors
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <% @employee.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li>
                    <%= message %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Firstname<span class="required"></span></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :emp_firstname, :required => true%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lastname<span class="required"></span></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :emp_lastname, :required => true %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address<span class="required"></span></td>
        <td><%= f.text_area :address, :required => true %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email_id<span class="required"></span></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :email_id, :required => true%></td>
    </tr>
```

controller create method,

```
 def create
   @employee = Employee.new
   @employee.emp_firstname = params[:employee][:emp_firstname]
   @employee.emp_lastname = params[:employee][:emp_lastname]
   @employee.address = params[:employee][:address]
   @employee.email_id = params[:employee][:email_id]
   @employee.comp_id = params[:company][:comp_id]
   @employee.dom_id = params[:domain][:dom_id]
     if @employee.save
       respond_to do |format|
               format.html {flash[:notice] = 'Employee was successfully created.' and redirect_to action: "index"}   
       end
     end
 end
```

When I save the new employee, there is no display of validation error messages. Template missing error is displayed. When I give correct format in the field, employee details are saved.Give me the correct way to display the validation error message.
Thank You.

Updation
 Before validation,mail is wrong, so it rollbacked.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2w/EyPI1+MGacWDXfX7fIE6VC5uDMlD9vbho+gXra1LD7U3XOzhLHoV5XSLmWwG5QY8tw9bOgMggMrt1/netdQ==", "employee"=>{"emp_firstname"=>"Aishwarya", "emp_lastname"=>"Prabha", "address"=>"xxxxxxx", "email_id"=>"dsfdsf"}, "company"=>{"comp_id"=>"1"}, "domain"=>{"dom_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Save"}(0.2ms) BEGIN(0.2ms) ROLLBACK
```

After correcting mail, is also rollback. not saved.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zxMM4m0F+aSejV+8UMk3gv3M3H2ueBz7xCppMEEQNqvX8YX9pAhKe4GFYknL7Okb8tb6JfuEzM5ZoLq/uozwjA==", "employee"=>{"emp_firstname"=>"Aishwarya", "emp_lastname"=>"Prabha", "address"=>"xxxxxxx", "email_id"=>"example@mail.com"}, "company"=>{"comp_id"=>""}, "domain"=>{"dom_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}(0.1ms)BEGIN(0.1ms)ROLLBACK
```

There dropdown in my form does not works. So com_id and dom_id becomes empty.

Comment: show your controller, especially `create` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting to the Index action if the object is successfully saved without any validation errors, **but what if there is an error?**

You should also handle the error case so that, **if the object is not saved it should render the new form** where the error messages are displayed.

According to your code in error case it is searching for create view file which is not present, so you should explicitly declare

**render 'new'** //check this line in else case

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

def create
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employee.emp_firstname = params[:employee][:emp_firstname]
    @employee.emp_lastname = params[:employee][:emp_lastname]
    @employee.address = params[:employee][:address]
    @employee.email_id = params[:employee][:email_id]
    @employee.comp_id = params[:company][:comp_id]
    @employee.dom_id = params[:domain][:dom_id]
      if @employee.save
        respond_to do |format|
                format.html {flash[:notice] = 'Employee was successfully created.' and redirect_to action: "index"}   
        end
      else
        render 'new' // This will show your error messages

      end
end
```

end

Thus, if the object's validation is failed, it will render to new action and then the validation messages will be displayed.

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you, you can accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: This answer is worked. But I am not have enough reputation to vote. Sorry for that.

Comment: Okay, Np you can do that once you get the reputation. Have a good day :)

Comment: While doing this, I get Roll back error. How can I overcome it

Comment: Sorry @Sravan I got the error again.I update the error code in the question. I update that.

Comment: You should give atleast one validation message, what's validates: address is doing, either give `validates: address, presence: true`, or remove it

Comment: Hey I got the result finally. :)))) Time out.once again thanks for your positive response

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: No @Sravan. That is dropdown error. It is from my controller. finally I fixed that..:). Have a nice day.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding :)